# How can we highlight good questions?

Tags: discussion

In these early days, how can we attract attention to the best questions? The current front page does not accurately reflect this. Keeping in mind that our goal is to invite experts, I think it would be great if we could manually curate a list of questions that we can tout as ideal questions for this SE.

(We could create a community wiki here with the answers as we discuss how to proceed)

Comment: I agree with you, and perhaps I should remove my biased list from the question and put it in an answer. I do not want to move attention away from the question in the title

Comment: Sounds good, I moved my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Harsh's list is a good start if we want to get people who think of themselves as AI experts, instead of people who think of themselves as AGI experts. (The G is for 'general.') But in order to differentiate this site from Cross Validated or Data Science, we're trying to focus on the humanities / philosophy side.

I worry that this means that we're going to have a parade of AI 101 questions, like [How does multiple intelligences fit in AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-multiple-intelligences-fit-in-ai) or [How does artificial intelligence Work in games?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/how-does-artificial-intelligence-work-in-games), which isn't an implementation or algorithms question because it's so broad and basic, or simple discussions of complicated issues, like the on-hold [Why does Stephen Hawking say "Artificial Intelligence will kill us all"?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7/why-does-stephen-hawking-say-artificial-intelligence-will-kill-us-all).

And this suggests that the AI experts are going to become rapidly bored and leave, since they can't ask the questions they're interested in and don't see any interesting questions to answer, and so they won't be around to contribute to the humanities side of the discussion. What good humanities questions have we had, so far? My short list is something like:

[What is the different between strong-AI and weak-AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-is-the-difference-between-strong-ai-and-weak-ai) (though this is another 101 question)

[Is the Turing Test, or any of its variants, a reliable test of artificial intelligence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15/is-the-turing-test-or-any-of-its-variants-a-reliable-test-of-artificial-intell)

[What limits, if any, does the halting problem put on Artificial Intelligence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-limits-if-any-does-the-halting-problem-put-on-artificial-intelligence)

But that's three good humanities questions out of the [15 currently most upvoted questions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that every site has a greatest hits page. Ours is at

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

Ours is currently empty, unfortunately, but I suspect that there will be questions there within a month or so. (An older site, Monero, still doesn't have any questions in this list. On the other hand, the Language Learning  site does, but that site is already three months old.)

Answer (score 1):

To give examples of questions I think are good, and that we should promote, in order with the best questions at the top:

- [How is it possible that deep neural networks are so easily fooled?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-is-it-possible-that-deep-neural-networks-are-so-easily-fooled) I would not have put "easily" in the title, but it is an excellent question that the AI experts I know spend a lot of time thinking about.
- [How does Hinton's "capsules theory" work?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/how-does-hintons-capsules-theory-work)
- [Is Lisp still being used to tackle AI problems?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-lisp-still-being-used-to-tackle-ai-problems)
- [What is the difference between MLP and RBF?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/227/what-is-the-difference-between-mlp-and-rbf) : This can go to Crossvalidated but I'd argue it's out of place there and more at home here. Though it is a comparison of two specific algorithms, it reflects wider design issues in AI algorithms.

Others may disagree on this list, but I'd like to put up here the questions I think are more on-topic here than I think in other SEs. Some overlap is inevitable.

Comment: All the questions you mention except for the third one Lisp are very much on-topic on stats and data science SE. The Lisp question might be on-topic on data science or stats, but unsure.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt They sure are.  The third one would be closed off though.

Answer (score 1):

These are some ways to highlight and promote nice content on the site:

1. Organizing a quarterly post, where people are encouraged to post their favourite qns/ans and the top three would be awarded bounties by the mods or whoever is interested in contributing.
2. Cross-posting the nice ones to other sites like reddit, etc. This would help in marketing the site, as well as good karma by sharing good content.

Answer (score 0):

### Add bounties.

What else can you do? Adding bounties to questions puts them in a special category on the front page. If you want, you could even have two users who 'bounce' a bounty to each other on  few questions, to make sure that they stay there in the 'featured' tab.

Comment: "If you want, you could even have two users who 'bounce' a bounty to each other on few questions, to make sure that they stay there in the 'featured' tab." – I'm quite sure that is considered abuse of the bounty system.

Comment: @wythagoras some top users did it on meta. And it's not *creating* extra rep, it's just bouncing.

Answer (score -3):

Upvote *only* good questions.

Down- and/or close-vote *all* bad questions.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is how to *bring extra attention* to the best questions.

Comment: I think it does, since the SE platform works off of votes (and bounties). In my experiencing, mediocre questions can become upvoted and downvotes rarely happen, thus leaving the field very even. More accentuated voting helps with that.